# Search and replace dynamically in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

```
$string = "On 0 8 February 2 0 1 4 , he visited the fair";
```

I want to replace the spaces between the numbers, so it becomes `"On 08 February 2014, he visited the fair"`

How can I do this with regex? I can do a for loop index by index, but given large amounts of text, it will be slow.

This is an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$string =~ s/([0-9]\s)+/substr($string,$-[0],$+[0]-$-[0])/g;
```

but it won't work since substr is not treated as a function within the regex. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use look behind, and look ahead to filter such spaces,

```
$string =~ s/[0-9]\K [ ]+ (?=[,0-9])//xg;
```

Comment: I did this $string =~ s/[0-9]\K [ ]+ (?=[[:punct:]0-9])//xg;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
do{
    $string =~s/(\d+)\s+(\d+)/$1$2/g;
} while($string =~/(\d+)\s+(\d+)/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following regex
`$string =~ s/(?<=\d)\s+(?![a-z])//ig;`